# Inequality for decreasing functions

Tags: analysis, inequality, extrapolation

While trying to prove some extrapolation theorem for $B_{p}$ weights, I tried to prove the following:

Suppose that $0<p\leq 1 $ and $w(x)$ is a non-negative and belongs to $B_{p}$, that is
\begin{equation}
\int_{r}^{\infty }\frac{w(x)}{x^{p}}dx\leq \frac{C_{1}}{r^{p}}%
\int_{0}^{r}w(x)dx. 
\end{equation}
then, the following inequality
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty }w(x)\left( \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\right) ^{p}dx\leq
C_{2}\int_{0}^{\infty }w(x)f^{p}(x)dx 
\end{equation}
holds for all non-negative, non-increasing functions $f(x)$.

Actually, I couldn't complete it since the exponent now $(p-1)$ is negative.

How can I prove the above result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just used the monotonicity of the function $f(t)$ to get it out from the inner integration and then the result follows directly. So, thanks for all your support and close the question, please.